# Convert JUnits to RESTful service

Tags: java, unit-testing, rest, junit

I want to run my JUnits on demand via RESTful api. These are primarily the functional JUnits which test the RESTful endpoints, so they don't directly test source code.

Is there any tooling available to scan existing JUnits and provide those a list of available tests along with the ability to execute those tests.

I am thinking of something which similar to the following REST calls  --

> 1. GET unit-test-service/tests  (to get the list of tests)
> 2. GET unit-test-service/tests/123456?execute=true (to execute the test and return test result as response.)

Any pointers are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Fitnesse](http://www.fitnesse.org) it is a simple wiki based testing tool having test classes in Java or other languages. It also has the REST urls where you can retrieve test cases as xml and parse it or run it as well.